# Margin/padding around content on a new Vue app

Tags: html, css, vue.js

Got a task to start developing a page in Vue for my team but I cannot  get rid of the white border around my entire page.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
</script>

<template>
  <body>
    <div></div>
  </body>
</template>

<style scoped>

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
}

</style>
```

[image]

It looks the same in the browser. From what I find people are just saying it's some standard margin/padding of the body. But setting those did not change anything. In my `main.ts` I have the remnants of the initial Vue Hello World/Welcome app, which imports a CSS file which itself also imports another one. But both are empty, and removing the initial import didn't help either.

Comment: Using `html`instead of `*` actually added more whitespace on the left and right. I've tried `body`as well, no difference then compared to `*`.

Comment: Try `html` or `body` rather than `*`. Also, please check your devtools to inspect where exactly this one is coming from. Also, you're using `scoped` here, but that one should be global to your project.

Comment: @kissu Alright, well that was the issue apparently. Removed `scoped` and now it's touching the edges. If you want to add that as an answer with an explanation I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the reset of the margin/padding in the global scope otherwise, it will stay within the realm of your component.
Please remove [the `scoped`](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#scoped-css) from your `style` or make that kind of reset higher in your file tree.

Also, I recommend not using the `*` CSS selector because that one is quite heavy in terms of performance impact. Please also use your devtools inspector to find out exactly why this is not applying the changes as you're expecting.

Comment: That fixed it. But why, where is this margin / padding coming from? If I remove the scoped, and also remove the body so it's only an `<div></div>` inside my template I still need the `body` CSS for the borders to go away. Is there a `body` element added by Vue itself somewhere?

Comment: @PatchingMatching this is the default style of pretty much all browsers, nothing more. Not directly related to Vue.

Comment: This is also inside `App.vue` by the way. So I figured that the scoped here would be basically my entire application anyways since it's at the very top. But you're saying that the preview / browser itself is adding a body somewhere that I need global scope styling to touch?

Comment: @PatchingMatching the opposite actually. Even the highest file in your tree (here `App.vue`) is still in a wrapper and not the body itself. It is actually better that way because an SPA is not tied to the DOM itself but in short: you cannot select the `body` via any `.vue` file. You need a generic un-scoped style to target `body`. It's not a huge deal at the end of the day, use a non-scoped style only for those 2/3 edge-cases and keep the rest as `scoped`.

Comment: I noticed that it was fine to have multiple style blocks, so I'll do that, and keep the body one alone in the global scope. Thanks a lot for the quick answers!

Comment: @PatchingMatching yep, having both `style` and `style scoped` is totally fine indeed.